# Image enlarge centering for Node D3 Force layout

Tags: javascript, image, d3.js, center

I am trying to do the following:

1. Click a node
2. Enlarge the image of that node according to its current width and height
3. The idea is to determine x,y position based on its own width and height so it does not run wild.

My code for force tick

```
function render(){
      force.on("tick", function() {
    node.attr("x", function(d) {return d.x-d.width/2})
        .attr("y", function(d) {return d.y-d.height/2});
```

Declaration of node

```
var node = container.append("g").selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href",function(d){return d.type+ ".svg" ;})
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("width", "24px")
    .attr("height", "24px")
    .attr("isChosen", "no")
    .on("click",click);
```

Sample of data

```
"nodes":[
    {"id":"0", "name":"ETCO I","type":"Company","trust":50},
    {"id": "1","name":"PINKERTON Eidel ","type":"human","trust":50}
     ],
"links":[
{"source":1,"target":0,"linktype":"Secretary"},
{"source":1,"target":0,"linktype":"Director"},
```

Click handle

```
function click(node)
 d3.select(this)
    .attr("isChosen", "yes")
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("x", function(d) {return d.x-24})
    .attr("y", function(d) {return d.y-24})
    .attr("width", "35px")
    .attr("height", "35px")
```

but it does not work, the image is all on left conner. Where does my logic go wrong?

Comment: Please add some sample data from 'graph.nodes' and the click listener so that the problem is more clear. What does `d.width` contains?

Comment: @Gilsha : Sorry, I am kinda new to this D3. I thought after you declare the node attr("width","24px"), it would stay like that and when render, if I call node d.width it would return 24px

Comment: To get the width attribute, use `parseInt(d3.select(this).style("width"))`

Comment: @Glisha; Just log in to thank you. Your answer helped me solve another critical problem. This one I am still struggling with. But thank you again. I will try to update the question more clear